# Clearing Python Console in QGIS using Python Command

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I'm developing a python script in which I use several "print" statements to view the intermediate results in python console of QGIS. Each time after executing the program, I have to manually clear the python console using "Clear Console" option.

Is there a way out to clear the printed statements in python console using a command?

I tried using the following command from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2370/62237)

```
qgis.console.clearConsole()
```

But I am getting this error message

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'console'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

QGIS offers you several classes for logging messages into the `Log Messages Panel` (i.e., no need to print debug messages from your plugin into the QGIS Python console). You could even easily create a tab in such a panel exclusively for your plugin using `QgsMessageLog` class:

```
from qgis.core import Qgis
QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "Info message from plugin", "My Plugin", Qgis.Info )
QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "My warning message", "My Plugin", Qgis.Warning )
QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "My critical message!!!", "My Plugin", Qgis.Critical )
QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "My success message", "My Plugin", Qgis.Success )
```

Having said that, you can clear the QGIS Python console with these 3 lines:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDockWidget
consoleWidget = iface.mainWindow().findChild( QDockWidget, 'PythonConsole' )
consoleWidget.console.shellOut.clearConsole()
```

Comment: That works !! Thanks for the info regarding Log messages panel

Comment: BTW, is there a command available to clear the previously logged messages upon new execution? @Germán Carrillo

Comment: Rapidly skimming through the API, I couldn't find such command.