# Deleting variables from the Python Console in a programmatic way?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I often use the **Python Console** for running some lines of code and I also use some *prints* for checking the validity of the results.

If I run this sample code:

```
a = 2
b = 4
res = a + b
print res
```

it will print the value of the `res` variable in the Python Console. However, if I then close the script tab, the `res` variable is still there. This means that, if I type `print res` in the Python Console, it will still return the last stored value.

I know that I can type:

```
del res
```

from the Python Console for deleting it. In fact, if I then type `print res`, I get:

```
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
```

as expected, but this is useful only when dealing with one or two variables and if I remember the names of these variables.

---

After a few searches, I found these questions:

[How to clear python console in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/how-to-clear-python-console-in-qgis)

[Clearing Python Console in QGIS using Python Command](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216437/clearing-python-console-in-qgis-using-python-command)

but their answers only explain how to ***clear*** the Python Console and not how to ***delete*** the variables.

---

Is there a programmatic way for deleting all the variables stored during the current QGIS session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to @bcollins answer, if you want to change your variables you have defined inside the QGIS python console you can try this approach:

Define a variable which holds all variables before you start programming:

```
my_dir = dir()
```

Do your magic with gis, for example:

```
 my_variable = 42
 my_other_variable = "foo"
```

Then do something like this:

```
for varis in dir():
   if varis not in my_dir and varis != "my_dir":
        print varis 
        exec("%s = None" % str(varis)) # set them to None
```

This way you get the all the variables which are **NOT** in `my_dir` and don't remove any other variables that were added by QGIS.

**Update:**
With the suggestion of @jon_two I try to combine the method of @bcollins and mine. This would be something like:

```
## after you finished your magic
my_new_dir = list(dir())
for varis in my_new_dir:
   if varis not in my_dir and varis != "my_dir":
        del locals()[varis]
```

Comment: Which should be the expected result?

Comment: the expected result would be, that when you typ in for example 'my_variable', that it returns None, but the variable name  would still exist. I though your aim is to free hd space. if not you could try @bcollins approach with 'del locals()[v]'

Comment: I think a combination of this and @bcollins approach would be best, though don't forget to take a copy of locals/dir otherwise it will keep updating as you cycle through it. `my_dir = list(dir())` or `my_locals = dict(locals())`.

Comment: @LaughU, thanks for the edit! Your approach compares the initial `dir()` with the final `dir()` and seems to do the trick independently from the name and the numbers of the variables involved. Even if this is more a workaround than a direct method, it is enough for me. Also, +1 for the perseverance.

Comment: @LaughU `my_new_dir = dir()` is just giving you a reference to `dir()`, so if you add a new local variable, it will also be added to `my_new_dir`. Using `my_new_dir = list(dir())` gives you a snapshot of `dir()` that will not be updated when variables are added to/deleted from local scope.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of builtin functions you should consider for this.

```
dir() will gives you the list of in scope variables
globals() will give you a dictionary of global variables
locals() will give you a dictionary of local variables
```

but you may run into trouble because you could inadvertently delete some variables that QGIS sets.  So something like this could get you started:

```
>>> my_var_res = 4
>>> my_vars = [v for v in locals().keys() if v.startswith('my_var')]
['my_var_res']
>>> for v in my_vars:
        del locals()[v]
```

I'm not claiming this is a good thing to do, just that it is possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but probably this doesn't solve the issue. In this way, I need to know the name of the variable for using `startswith()` and doesn't seems a programmatic way for solving the problem. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

A method which I used a while ago was to begin each variable name with an underscore ("_"). As there are no other variables beginning with a single underscore (only double), you can search for all these variables and delete them accordingly:

```
# Define user variables
_foo1 = "Hello world"
_foo2 = "bar"
_foo3 = {"1":"a", "2":"b"}
_foo4 = "1+1"

# Create list containing user variables
my_vars = []
for var in dir():
    if var.startswith('_') and not var.startswith('__'):
        my_vars.append(var)

# Delete specific user variable
for x in my_vars:
    if '_foo1' in x:
        del globals()[x]

# Delete all user variables
for x in my_vars:
    del globals()[x]
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but I think that solution the by @LaughU could be more versatile because it avoids the using of the underscore for all the variables involved.

Comment: @mgri - Most welcome and I agree, I found it quite a pain for having to constantly add an underscore for each variable. Fortunately, I didn't have to work with this for very long :)

Comment: As you can imagine, my question was more a curiosity than a real need. =)

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following for globals

At the beginning of the session, store keys from your global context e.g

```py
myglobals = set(globals().keys())
```

Later, to know what you need to clean, you will get the `difference` method from the `set` using

```py
set(globals().keys()).difference(myglobals)
```

To remove all globals variables, except `myglobals` used to keep state info in your PyQGIS console, do

```py
for g in set(globals().keys()).difference(myglobals):
    if g != 'myglobals':
        del globals()[g]
```